# R Code count the number of occurrences in percentage for the selected column

Tags: r, csv

I hope you have a good day.
I am new to R Code
I have a CSV file which consists of 10 000 rows which is constantly changing and I will show the top 11 rows including the header. I need to perform the counting of number of time the data(percentage) in some of the columns such as Location, Group and Available.

```
Number  Group or Place   Location    Available   Size
1         A              Los Angeles  YES       10
2         A              New York     NO        11 
3         A              NA           YES       12
4         A              Chicago      NO        13 
5         B              Los Angeles  NA        14
6         B              Houston      YES       15
7         B              Houston      NO        16
8         C              Chicago      YES       17
9         C              Chicago      YES       18
10        D              New York     NO        19
```

I want to create an output and show in excel file. Basically I want to select column such as Group, Location and Available and show the percentage of each unique value including missing value and how many time it appear in percentage over the total number of columns. The NA refer to empty value. Here is how the output should looks like in excel

```
Column Name      Values        Percentage(occurrence%)
Group or Place        A             40 (40%)
                      B             30 (30%)
                      C             20 (20%)
                      D             10 (10%)
Location     Los Angeles   20 (20%)
             Chicago       30 (30%)
             NA            10 (10%)
             Houston       20 (20%)
             New York      20 (20%)
Available    YES           50 (50%)
             NO            40 (40%)
             NA            10 (10%)
```

This is my R code. I perform the counting of number of each value but NA is not included. I am unable to figure out on how to get the percentage of each unique value including the missing value over the total number of columns and export to excel file.

```
exceldata <- read.csv("group.csv") 
view(exceldata) # view the whole csv
str(exceldata)  #str() function we can see that we have many observations across 5 columns
table(exceldata['Group or Place'])  #show the number of each value and the number of time it occurred under group column 
table(exceldate['Location']) #show the number of each value and the number of time it occurred under Location column
table(exceldata$Group or Place)/length(exceldata$Group or Place) # It shows the value similar to percentage.
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Number,    ~Group,    ~Location,   ~Available,   ~Size,
1 ,       "A",        "Los Angeles",  "YES",      10,
2 ,       "A",        "New York",     "NO",        11, 
3 ,       "A",        NA_character_,           "YES",      12,
4 ,       "A",        "Chicago",      "NO",        13, 
5 ,       "B",        "Los Angeles",  NA_character_,      14,
6 ,       "B",        "Houston",      "YES",       15,
7 ,       "B",        "Houston",      "NO",      16,
8 ,       "C",        "Chicago",      "YES",       17,
9 ,       "C",        "Chicago",      "YES",      18,
10,       "D",        "New York",     "NO",        19)


library(tidyverse)

dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(Group:Available, names_to = "var", values_to="cat") %>% 
  group_by(var, cat) %>% 
  summarise(Size = sum(Size)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  group_by(var) %>% 
  mutate(Percent = Size/sum(Size), 
  Percent = sprintf("%.0f (%.0f%%)", Percent*100, Percent*100))

  # # A tibble: 12 × 4
  # # Groups:   var [3]
  #   var       cat          Size Percent 
  #   <chr>     <chr>       <dbl> <chr>   
  # 1 Available NO             59 41 (41%)
  # 2 Available YES            72 50 (50%)
  # 3 Available NA             14 10 (10%)
  # 4 Group     A              46 32 (32%)
  # 5 Group     B              45 31 (31%)
  # 6 Group     C              35 24 (24%)
  # 7 Group     D              19 13 (13%)
  # 8 Location  Chicago        48 33 (33%)
  # 9 Location  Houston        31 21 (21%)
  # 10 Location  Los Angeles    24 17 (17%)
  # 11 Location  New York       30 21 (21%)
  # 12 Location  NA             12 8 (8%)
```

This assumes that you want to sum up `Size` to identify the percentages.

Comment: I tried to load the code in r studio and it did not work.

Comment: There was a missing close parenthesis at the end of the final mutate command.  I fixed it in the answer.

Comment: Assuming if I want to select some of the columns but instead of using the colon. How do I achieve it?

Comment: @jerometan you could just make a vector of variable names e.g., `c("Group", "Location", "Size")` and use that in place of `Group:Available`.